# Deserialize an XML string based on class file generated with XSD

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize an XML answer based on classes created by XSD schema but it always returns null.

The XML file has this format

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Responses xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <Response>
        <inv_number>1</inv_number>
        <StatusCode>Success</StatusCode>
        <Uid>271D95D28716B37A330A5A476AE530206828B103</Uid>
        <Mark>1000000912965</Mark>
      </Response>
      <Response>
        <inv_number>2</inv_number>
        <StatusCode>ValidationError</StatusCode>
        <Errors>
          <Error>
            <Message>Author AFM is not the same with User AFM</Message>
            <Code>-1</Code>
          </Error>
        </Errors>
      </Response>
</Responses>
```

My class file based on XSD schema (generated with xsd.exe) is:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.6.1055.0.
// 


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class ResponseDoc {

    private ResponseType[] responseField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("response")]
    public ResponseType[] response {
        get {
            return this.responseField;
        }
        set {
            this.responseField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class ResponseType {

    private int entitylineNumberField;

    private string statusCodeField;

    private object[] itemsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int entitylineNumber {
        get {
            return this.entitylineNumberField;
        }
        set {
            this.entitylineNumberField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string statusCode {
        get {
            return this.statusCodeField;
        }
        set {
            this.statusCodeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("entityMark", typeof(long))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("entityUid", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("errors", typeof(ResponseTypeErrors))]
    public object[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class ResponseTypeErrors {

    private ErrorType[] errorField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("error")]
    public ErrorType[] error {
        get {
            return this.errorField;
        }
        set {
            this.errorField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class ErrorType {

    private string messageField;

    private int codeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string message {
        get {
            return this.messageField;
        }
        set {
            this.messageField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public int code {
        get {
            return this.codeField;
        }
        set {
            this.codeField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

My code of deserialize the XML answer is

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ResponseType),new XmlRootAttribute("Responses"));
ResponseType resultingResponse = (ResponseType)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(result));
```

If I don't put the

> new XmlRootAttribute("Responses")

it gives me an exception

```
system.invalidOperaionException  <Responses xmlns=''> was not expected.
```

If I use it it just gives me empty results.
I also tried deleting the

> [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44522736/7054211) but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            //read past the unicode in first line
            sReader.ReadLine();

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ResponseDoc));
            ResponseDoc responseDoc = (ResponseDoc)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Responses", Namespace = "")]
    public partial class ResponseDoc
    {

        private ResponseType[] responseField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(ElementName = "Response", Namespace = "")]
        public ResponseType[] response
        {
            get
            {
                return this.responseField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.responseField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Response", Namespace = "")]
    public partial class ResponseType
    {

        private int entitylineNumberField;

        private string statusCodeField;

        private string uid;

        private long entityMark;


        private ResponseTypeErrors[] responseTypeErrors;

        /// <remarks/>
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "inv_number", Namespace = "")]
        public string entitylineNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return this.entitylineNumberField.ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                this.entitylineNumberField = int.Parse(value);
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "StatusCode", Namespace = "")]
        public string statusCode
        {
            get
            {
                return this.statusCodeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.statusCodeField = value;
            }
        }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Uid", Namespace = "")]
        public string Uid
        {
            get
            {
                return this.uid;
            }
            set
            {
                this.uid = value;
            }
        }


        [XmlElement(ElementName = "entityMark", Namespace = "")]
        public string EntityMark
        {
            get
            {
                return this.entityMark.ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                this.entityMark = long.Parse(value);
            }
        }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Errors", Namespace = "")]
        public ResponseTypeErrors[] Errors
        {
            get
            {
                return this.responseTypeErrors;
            }
            set
            {
                this.responseTypeErrors = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Errors", Namespace = "")]
    public partial class ResponseTypeErrors
    {

        private ErrorType[] errorField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Error")]
        public ErrorType[] error
        {
            get
            {
                return this.errorField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.errorField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Error", Namespace = "")]
    public partial class ErrorType
    {

        private string messageField;

        private int codeField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Message", Namespace = "")]
        public string message
        {
            get
            {
                return this.messageField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.messageField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Code", Namespace = "")]
        public int code
        {
            get
            {
                return this.codeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.codeField = value;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't have the XML in file but when I put the string instead of the filename it throws argument exception "illegal characters in path.”

Comment: If I try with external XML file and your XSD schema is working but it doesnt return the entityMark.With my code is this a problem with the xsd generated classes or the XML file itself?

Comment: I updated code to add Entity Mark.  I think it is with the xsd file.  The xsd is not generating classes that are compatible with Xml file.  So it could be either the Xml or Xsd.  But looking at the code generated : public object[] Items (and the attributes above the code) it looks wrong.  I've never seen "entityMark" (a long), "entityUid" (a string), and "errors" (an array of classes) combined into a single type.  The xsd.exe is using instructions in the XSD file to put these three objects into one property in the class.  So I think the XSD is wrong.

Comment: This works but I still can't read the XML stream that they send as answer

Comment: It is very hard to debug xml deserialization.  The error message generate by c# does not give good info.  Usually I have to comment and uncomment the class properties (or xml) to find what is wrong.  I suspect the schema (xsd) file was not verified against the xml sent by the supplier.

Comment: I believe that is the encoding. When I try to save the file in notepad++ it says that "document labeled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content". In your code you skip this line. Can I do that with the stream as well because I can't use StreamReader with actual XML data, I have to use a file .

Comment: Use StringReader(string) instead (or any stream where you can read a line).

Comment: Great, with StringReader I can read the XML fine. I will the classes that you created because it seem to working fine. Thanks again